# Rails: Errors displayed on terminal, but not in HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

What goes wrong here?

The errors are there and displayed on the terminal. Please see on the right of the screenshot.

But it isn't shown there in HTML.

[image: Screenshot]

The relevant source-code:

```
<% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <h3>Errors ...</h3>
     <% puts "Errors ..." %>
        <ul>
            <% @article.errors.each do |error| %>
                <% puts error.full_message %>
                <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
<% else %>
    <h3>All is fine.</h3>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are you using turbo? It looks to me like the form gets not replaced with the newly rendered from the server after returning from the request. Did you double-check your javascript/turbo setup?

Comment: @spickermann It's Rails 7. But I have nothing done concerning turbo. Is that something enabled by default?

Comment: @spickermann Your theory about the form might be right. It seems to be something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Using <% puts %> will still render to console, if you would like to have it in html just remove the `puts`

remember that the html is rendered on the server side and that any ruby code that is inside those angle brackets is executed on the server, so the puts is executed on the server and written to STDOUT

Comment: I removed the puts. But there must be something else, which prevents it from working. It wasn't the puts.

Comment: You can try adding `form_with .... , 'data-turbo': false do |x|`